# Java not working in Google Chrome Lubuntu 14.04 (32-bit)

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, java

I have Java 1.7.0_55 installed I have gotten it to work on firefox. My installed chrome version is Version 35.0.1916.114.

I have already created the plugins folder in the chrome directory and made a symbolic link to libnpjp2.so within the chrome plugins folder, restarted the browser and java is still not working. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 35 no longer supports oracle java on linux...

http://guaranteedtofail.com/chrome-35-and-java/

Comment: Consider adding more details from the site you reference, in case it becomes a dead link in the future.